# Application failed codesign verification warning

Tags: ios, code-signing

I got this warning in XCode today when I start running my app on my iPad.

> Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid,
>   contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone
>   Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

It is saying that the app's provisioning profile was not signed with a distribution certificate. But I just submitted my app yesterday and switched back my distribution provisioning profile to development provisioning profile. XCode shouldn't think I am still building for distribution. I can still run my app but I can't see any debugging information now. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: did you try a clean and rebuild?

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: check in keychain certificat is expire or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Build settings -> Validate Built Product

Debug: YES changes to NO

Release: No changes to YES

and the warning goes away.

I think I've had some misunderstanding of "Validate Built Product" section before.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, go to Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme and make sure that your current scheme build configuration is set to debug.